# Javascript RegEx to validate file name pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to validate file name with following pattern....

1. File name(string) should not be null or empty
2. File name(string) should have extension as .INI
3. File name(string) should have "gen1" or "gen2" or "gen3"... genN where N has to be number.

We have already done the implementation with Javascript string functions but it looked little messy..

I am really interested in Validation-3 of "genN" which can be done more gracefully with RegEx

Comment: minitech's answer below raises a good point. Can you clarify what you mean by "should have 'gen1'"? That is -- can you give some examples of valid filenames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "should have `genN`", do you mean:

- Should be named gen#.ini?

  ```
  /^gen\d\.ini$/i
  ```
- Should contain `gen#`?

  ```
  /^.*gen\d.*\.ini$/i
  ```

Also, if you want more than `0` to `9` in those, change `\d` to `\d+`. If you only want to accept 1 and onwards, `[1-9]`. Both these requirements? `[1-9]\d*`.

---

[Here's a helpful picker](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/HHMVr/) that should make the right regular expression for you.

Comment: Thanks Minitech... worked perfectly bud... You should have opt for maxtech avatar... :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree, this sounds perfectly suited to regexes. Assuming that `N` has to be a positive decimal integer, and it can't have leading `0`s, you can write:

```
/^gen[1-9][0-9]*\.INI$/
```

which means "start-of-string (`^`), followed by `gen`, followed by a digit in the range `1-9`, followed by zero or more (`*`) digits in the range `0-9`, followed by a literal dot (`\.`), followed by `INI`, followed by end-of-string (`$`)".